# Proof Verification: If $a\leq x_n \leq b$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_n\to L$, then $a\leq L\leq b.$

Tags: proof-verification

I have to use the definition of convergence only to prove this. This is my attempt on proving this statement:

> Let $\epsilon >0$. Then, we know there is some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such
>   that for all $n \geq N$ we have $|x_n-L| < \epsilon$. Thus,
>
> $$|x_n-L|<\epsilon$$ $$\Leftrightarrow L-\epsilon<x_n<L+\epsilon$$
>   Since $a \leq x_n \leq b$, we can deduce that  $$L-\epsilon<b \implies
> > L<b+ \epsilon$$ $$a < L+\epsilon \implies a-\epsilon < L$$ And
>   $a-\epsilon <L < b+\epsilon$.  $\blacksquare$

This is as far as I can get but does the last statement imply that $a\leq L \leq b$? Since we can make $\epsilon$ as small as we want, $a-\epsilon <L < b+\epsilon$ will eventually becomes $a < L <b$ but it doesn't necessarily mean $a\leq L \leq b$.

EDIT: Also, how can I place my black box (QED symbol) to the corner?

Comment: You're right. More formally, since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, this is true for all $\epsilon > 0$. Now argue by contradiction: if $a>L$, then for $\epsilon = a-L$, we have $a - (a - L) < L$, i.e. $0<0$. Same applies for $b$.

Comment: If $L$ were $a$ (or $b$), then it would satisfy $a-\epsilon<L<b+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, but it would not satisfy $a<L<b$. In other words, when you drop $\epsilon$ to 0, the statement you should end up with is $a\leq L\leq b$, and not $a<L<b$.

Comment: @RideTheWavelet What about for the possibility of $b<L<b+\epsilon$? Since we don't know yet if $a \leq L \leq b$, isn't it possible for $L>b$ and $L<a$?

Comment: @OpenBall That is much better proof! Thank you.

Comment: Please don't use proof-verification tag as the only tag on your question. Use other tags to indicate what area of mathematics the proof comes from.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Sorry, I will keep that in mind for my next questions!